# Read param names of a particular template in an XSLT

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am working in Visual Studio 2012 with C#.

I want to read all the param names of particular template in a XSLT file. For a particular template I wrote the below code (`templateName` is the name of the template in the XSLT file):

```
XmlNodeList templateParam = (XmlNodeList)xslDoc.SelectNodes("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template/[@name = '" + templateName + "']/xsl:param/@name", nsMgr);
```

It shows an error

> Expression must evaluate to a node-set.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also, do not include IDE tag (Visual Studio) among tags if your question is not directly about it and you just write code in it. Problems with code are seldom connected to a code editor.

Comment: Thanks for the information Ondrej. May be you could right something about the possible solution also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `/` after `xsl:template`:

```
XmlNodeList templateParam = (XmlNodeList)xslDoc.SelectNodes("/xsl:stylesheet/xsl:template[@name = '" + templateName + "']/xsl:param/@name", nsMgr);
```

Caveat: I am well-versed in XSLT only, not C#.